# Logging in with Prepared Statements - Can't log in with username/password

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, prepared-statement

I am using prepared statements to log in, but I am not able to log in with any password and username pairs. I don't know why. It seems like `$result = $stmt->get_result();` never returns false because when I print `$result`, I get:

```
result: mysqli_result Object (
     [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0
)
```

How do I fix this?

**Code**

```
if(isset($_POST["Logsub"])){
    if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])){
        $username = filter_var($_POST["username"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $password_sanitized = filter_var($_POST["password"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = hash( "sha256", $password_sanitized ); //"sha256" is a type of hashing algorithm 

        if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $username)&& preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $password)){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
            $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

            if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password );
                $stmt->execute();

                //Returns a resultset for successful SELECT queries, or FALSE
                $result = $stmt->get_result();

                //If results (query for username and password that was entered) returns false
                if(!$result) {
                    echo "<div class = 'message'> Invalid username or password. Please try again </div>";
                } else {
                    echo "<div class = 'message'> You Have Been Successfully Logged In. </div>";
                }
            }
            $stmt->close(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

**Database**

```
`login` (`username`, `password`) VALUES (username, 'someHashedPassword');
```

Comment: It's not advisable to escape or sanitize passwords, especially when it comes to ones such as `123'\abc` being perfectly valid. In escaping those, it will rewrite it as `123\'\abc` in turn failing on `password_verify()`, if and when you use `password_hash()` to store the hashed password with, which you should; the sha family isn't so great.

Comment: sanitise filter and preg_match not much point doing both and you shouldn't actually do either

Comment: Okay should I do run `trim`, `stripslashes`, and `htmlspecialchars` on the password instead? Would `'tiger192,3'` be a better hash algorithm?

Comment: @Fred -ii- should I run `htmlspecialchars` instead of sanitizing?

Comment: @nogad what would be recommended instead?

Comment: nada zip zero, if not empty test against db.

Answer (score 0):

`get_results` returns FALSE when it fails, otherwise it returns the dataset asked in the prepared statement. You are getting 0 rows, meaning that there is no user with such username and password. You are relying on FALSE instead of 0 rows to show that username or password is incorrect, which is wrong. It will only return FALSE if there was any error executing the prepared statement.
If you are concerned about why 0 results are returning and expect correct login, it can happen if the calculated hash of your password is not matching the hash which is stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

Un-filtered approach:

```
if(isset($_POST["Logsub"]) && !empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])){
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=hash("sha256",$_POST["password"]);
    $query="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=? AND password=?";
    if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query)){
        if($stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password) &&
           $stmt->execute() && 
           $stmt->store_result()
        ){
            if($result=$stmt->get_result()){
                echo "<div class=\"message\">You have been successfully logged in.</div>";
            }else{
                echo "<div class=\"message\">Invalid username or password. Please try again.</div>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Statement Error: ",$stmt->error;  // do not echo when public
        }
        $stmt->close(); 
    }else{
        echo "Prepare Error: ",$mysqli->error;  // do not echo when public
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}else{
    echo "Insufficient or invalid credentials submitted";
}
```

- You can combine your two initial condition statements into one.
- You are likely damaging the password value while filtering/sanitizing.  You can trust your prepared statement to keep your query safe from injection;  all of that pre-filtering is unnecessary.
- `$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();` is in the manual but prepared statements will work without it (most people just put the dbh directly on prepare; this is my preference).
- I have batched all of the stmt actions into one condition statement.  If any of the conditions fail, php will immediately go to else condition and display the error.
- I declared `$result` just in case you want to use it in your actual project.

If this code block doesn't permit login with the correct credentials, please echo out your `$query`, `$username`, and hash'ed `$password` glue it all together and run it directly on your database to ensure that it does/can match a row.

(*I did not test this code before posting)